# Sending a request to my http server hangs indefinitely in CI environment (CircleCI andgithub actions). Works as expected locally

Tags: python, c++, bash, server, circleci

So I’m writing a basic http server in c++ for school. At the moment my service can receive a request and send a basic response. I’m writing a basic acceptance test with python requests and executing it in a shell script by running the webserver in the background and then running the python client. Locally (on Mac) running the tests it works fine, also on a custom ubuntu docker container, which is also used for my config.yml file.
But when running the tests on circleCI the client seems to be accepted but the GET request is not being received and the program hangs.
Does anyone know why this is and how to solve it?
Please not that the include code is still being developed so be kind :slight_smile:

My config.yml:

```
version: 2

jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: "rynosaurusrex/ci_for_codam:webserv"
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run:
          name: Build
          command: 'echo Building'
      - run:
          name: Unit-Test
          command: "make test && ./unit_test"
      - run:
          name: Acceptance-Test
          command: make acceptence
```

My basic python GET request:

```
import time
import requests
from requests import Session
from enum import Enum

class Colors:
    OKGREEN =   '\033[92m'
    FAILRED =   '\033[91m'
    NATURAL =   '\033[0m'

OK              = 200
BAD_REQUEST     = 400
NOT_FOUND       = 404
URI_TOO_LONG    = 414
TEAPOT          = 418
NOT_IMPLEMENTED = 501

localhost = "http://localhost:80"
EXIT_CODE = 0

print("Connecting to server...")
r = requests.get(localhost)
print("Request send!")

if r.status_code != OK:
    print(f"{Colors.FAILRED}[KO] {Colors.NATURAL} Get request on http://localhost:80")
    EXIT_CODE = 1;
else:
    print(f"{Colors.OKGREEN}[OK] {Colors.NATURAL} Get request on http://localhost:80")

# sleep so that the exit code is that of the python script and not the server
time.sleep(1)
exit(EXIT_CODE)
```

and my messy bash script to run everything:

```
#!/bin/bash
# the & runs a command/program in the background
./Webserver.out &

# Save the PID to kill the webserv
PID=$!
# sleep for 2 second to make sure the server has time to start up
sleep 2

# run the tests
# curl localhost:80
python3 acceptence_tests/TestClient.py 
# save the return val of the tests for CI
T1=$?

kill $PID
exit $T1
```

So I print a few status updates when running the tests. When printing `Accepted client on fd 4`the accept() call was succesful but the request doesn’t seem to be coming through, possible a handshake issue? As mentioned above, running this locally and directly in the container delivers the expected results, how does local ports work within CircleCI?

[image]

I've tried changing the request to https with port 443, also 0.0.0.0 and it seems like the `handshake` is failing any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If the problem is in your server code, please include your server code in the question.

Comment: Listening on port 80 (and also on port 443) usually requires administrator privilidges. Can you try an unrestricted port (e.g. 8080)? Of course you also have to make your webserver listen on that port then.

Comment: On the other hand, according to your screenshot, the listening on port 80 seems to work...

Comment: @JakobStark cool I didn't know that, unfortunately the same result, locally it accepts, parses the request, and responds with a standard response....

Comment: `./acceptence_tests/acceptence.sh
Creating Webserv instance with port: 8080
Connecting to server...
Accepting new client...
Accepted client on fd: 4
Host: localhost:8080
User-Agent: python-requests/2.26.0
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept: */*
Connection: keep-alive


Send to 4: 
HTTP/1.1 200
content-length: 17

SERVER GOES BRRRR
Removing client: 4
Request sent!
[OK]  Get request on http://localhost:8080`
This is the full desired output.

Comment: Hm you also don't get the `Connection to server...` message in your screenshot. Maybe the client did not start correctly? Weird because the server says `Accepted client...`...

Comment: Yea indeed, good spot, also when trying to connect with curl and not the python client... Any ideas?

Comment: You can give the verbose flag (`curl -v ...`) to curl. It should show you exactly what it is doing while trying to connect. Maybe you can spot something there.

Comment: Nice another trick learnt :)
As Far as I can see the connection is successfully made, `Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)` but doesn't continue after that... mmmmm frustration station

Comment: Ok I think this is an issue within your server. Apparently the TCP connection is successfully established, but the server does not correctly respond to data that is send. It might be time to debug the code. Of course you probably cannot use a debugger in the CircleCI environment and that is the place where it does not work. I would suggest using good old print debugging. Try to insert many print statements into your server code to track what it does. Does it receive data? If yes, is that data complete? Print it! Does the server try to write data? If yes what data? I have one more clue...

Comment: Ok awesome, thanks for your patience and help Jakob!
So yea the data it is trying to write is a simply reply which is always constant just to check the two way comms.
Print statements it is :D
Hopefully I can return soon with an answer and a resolved issue :)

Comment: Is the clue a reward for debugging first...? ;)

Comment: ...spotted in your code: In line [Client.cpp:25](https://github.com/Ryno95/webserv/blob/42bd90617192f6a97ebaa7462834148d4c714f08/srcs/Client.cpp#L25) you read data from the socket. But if it returns only part of the data, it must be called again. Are you sure you handled this correctly? The actual number of `receivedBytes` is never used... Note that `recv` is allowed to read less bytes than requested.

Comment: @Ryno no it is not a reward ;) I just needed time to understand parts of your code... I wish you good luck with debugging!

Comment: Soooo some updates, I spoke to some other people doing this project, everyone seems to be having an issue with the CI environment, be it circle ci or github actions. However the CI environment is wrapped, it seems to be interfering with the way the requests are sent and received. Trying to change the docker to have root privileges on CI, but circleCI is down today, fun fun fun.

Comment: @JakobStark as for the recv() call, a specification of the server is for it to be non-blocking, so fo every poll() call we read/recv once, so that it doesn't get stuck on reading a massive request. As for the received bytes, it only matters when returning 0 or -1, and then for the body to compare it to the content length field (which we haven't implemented yet).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be caused by trying to run as root in your container, since this could be blocked/limited by the host system (which is configured/owned by circleCI/github in this case) for security reasons. You could try explicitly creating and using a separate user in your Dockerfile, avoiding weird permission issues.

As an example, if you add this to your Dockerfile you'll use `test_user` instead of `root`:

```
RUN useradd -m test_user
USER test_user
```

Comment: Amazing! This solves the issue! Thanks a million!